# does vtiger has incoming popup webservice?

Tags: asterisk, voip, vtigercrm

I want integrate vtiger 6 with asterisk 11.
I Configue   "connector for asterisk" but not work.
I want send CallerId To Asterisk With AGI ,
does vtiger has webservice for incoming popup to send the parameters?

Answer (score -1):

Yes, vtiger connector for asterisk do popup.
No, it have no parameters.

However at current moment vtiger connector not work with modern asterisk version, seams like they not care about.

There are no source code of that connector availible, so it have be rewrited.

You can write new module or ask someone do that.

Comment: thanks arheops.yes can get CallerId With AMI(asterisk manager interface) but what url or vtiger webservice send callerid؟

Comment: Check module source code. It have special script, ajax part, handler.